# How to covert document file in pdf with same formatting using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf, mpdf

How to covert document file in pdf with same formatting using Laravel?
Currently, I have one template document folder. In document folder have many file this file i am use for user. This file are use as template file like email after that put same for update as user requirement. This this working properly.

I am stored this file as doc format but I want to download in PDF format. Its working fine but PDF download file content not set properly like doc file. I am facing is issue in PHP(Laravel).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can not convert a file to docx format with Laravel itself. You need to install [php imagemagick](https://phpimagick.com/) extension to your application. But with PHP IMAGEMAGICK, images can be converted to pdfs, to convert a file to docx you need use third party libraries.

Comment: Thanks for reply ,Please suggest third party API